# Objective-c obfuscation of methods works in DEBUG but crashes in RELEASE

Tags: objective-c, ios, configuration, frameworks, build

I made a xcode project where i did some security stuff and they asked me to obfuscate the method names

like so

```
#define specialMethod a9328238
+(void) specialMethod
{
   // do security stuff
}
```

i made a .framework library from the project ( project A ) and included it into another project ( project B ).

but when i run (project B) with a Release build configuration it always crashes like so.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SecurityClass a9328238]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x337cc4'
```

so it crashes when it tries to acces the method.

But when i run (project B) it with a Debug build configuration it runs smooth

**(i have kept all my build configuration settings as default)**

Comment: what is in your Compiler Flags?

Comment: Does it work in release build without obfuscated method names?

Comment: What is they say about security by obscurity?

Comment: It works without obfuscation.

Comment: Maybe you should say more about how the obfuscation is getting used-- the way you show in your example, with a `#define` immediately before  a method definition (in a .m file) won't make that name visible to callers (though that's not obviously the cause of the error you're seeing, so I suspect you're condensing your code)

Comment: I feel the same way as @JeremyP. This whole thing does not have anything to do with security. It will make hacking a slightly more difficult but it won't increase security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where have you placed the `#define` for obfuscation ? Is it in the header file (`.h`) or in the implementation file (`.m`) of the framework ?

For the obfuscation to be effective, it must be placed in a file that is both included by the implementation and the caller.

You can also check that the pre-processing is ok by inspecting the pre-processed file. Select the implementation file and go to the menu `Product > Generate Output > Generate Preprocessed File` (you can select the configuration at the bottom of the screen).

Comment: Viewing the pre-processed result is also possible via the assistant editor.

Answer (score 2):

My hunch is the `#define` location/visibility as well.

But you may want to consider this from another angle. You could change:

```
#define specialMethod a9328238
+(void) specialMethod
{
   // do security stuff
}
```

to:

```
@interface SecurityClass : NSObject

// private obfuscated interface:
+ (void)a9328238;
// {
//    do security stuff in a9328238's definition
// }

@end

// here is the public interface:
static inline void SecurityClass_LogIn() {
   [SecurityClass a9328238];
}
```

dropping `#define` altogether.

In use:

```
SecurityClass_LogIn();
…
```

Since this is a class method, you could write an obfuscated function wrapped in a human readable inline instead. A well crafted C implementation will be much more difficult to pick apart than objc.

A more complete example would help us narrow down the possibilities.

Also verify there are no warnings -- the compiler may warn you if you have called an undeclared selector. It's possible that the method is called where the `#define` is not visible in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the executable which imports the obfuscated framework tries to access the non-obfuscated methods.

You should check the symbols in the framework. Use `nm` on the static library in the framework to see the exported symbols (marked with a 't'). Make sure the symbols are obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

If you've wrapped everything into a framework, have you made sure that the appropriate headers are exposed outside of the framework? Headers inside a framework aren't exposed the same way as normal files are. Go to your **Project->Build Phases, in the bottom right you should see "Add Copy Headers"**. This will add a new section in your build phases. Inside this section, click the "+" and the headers that define your method names.